# In WP8 adding tile for web site programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8, bookmarks, tile

I'm trying to add a tile to the start screen for my web site programmatically.

Is there a way to do that via javascript?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
http://www.emoticode.net/html/create-windows-phone-8-tile-for-your-site.html
or  more explanation here:
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/19/creating-a-custom-tile-to-link-to-your-website.aspx